# "Unable to infer closure type in the current context" sorting array of arrays in swift

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary of dictionaries which I have converted to an array or arrays to use in a tableView but before I do I want to sort the arrays by their timestamp, which is at index 0 within each sub-array. When I try to use .sort I get an error "Unable to infer closure type in the current context". I have also tried many different syntax versions of .sort as well as creating a new array using .sorted. The code is all within a view controller. Any reason why this shouldn't work?

```
   for ident in inbox.allKeys {
        let info = inbox[ident] as! NSDictionary
        let timestamp = info["timestamp"] as! Int
        let question = info["question"]
        let status = info["status"]
        var rorm: String!

        if info["type"] as! String == "always_sender" {
            rorm = (info["responder"] as! String)
        }
        else if info["type"] as! String == "always_reply"{
            rorm = (info["reply"] as! String)
        }
        let out = [timestamp, ident, rorm, question, status]
        tableData.append(out)
    }
    tableData.sort(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

Comment: What is the type of `tableData` and `inbox` respectively?

Comment: Probably you mean `tableData.sort(by: { $0[0] < $1[0] })`. `0.0` is related to a tuple or a dictionary.

Comment: @sweeper I declare inbox and tableData as follows `var inbox: NSDictionary!`
    `var tableData: [Array<Any>] = []`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to be

`self.tableData.sort { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
        return (obj1[0] as! Int) < (obj2[0] as! Int)
 }`

I believe the issue was that the timestamp was unwrapped as an Any instead of an Int

Answer (score 0):

first you seem to instantiate `out` with an heterogeneous collection because `timestamp` is an `Int` and `rorm` is of type `String`. If it is indented you must explicitly type annotate this with `[Any]`.

Second, `out` is an array and `tableData` and array of arrays so you should access indexes with the subscript syntax:

```
tableData.sort(by: { $0[0] < $1[0] })
```

Comment: I changed out to the following `let out: [Any] = [timestamp, ident, rorm, question, status]` and changed the sort to what you recommended but I still get the same error

Comment: Provide an example input dictionary please.

Comment: `inbox = {
    1 =     {
        question = "How are you";
        reply = "good";
        responder = first_person;
        result = 0;
        status = 1;
        timestamp = 1586966857;
        type = "always_sender";
    };
    2 =     {
        question = "How are you";
        reply = "fine";
        responder = second_person;
        result = 1;
        status = 0;
        timestamp = 1586966864;
        type = "always_reply";
    };
    }`

Comment: Also if I print `tableData` where the sort is I get this `[[1586966857, "1", "first_person", "How are you", true], [1586966864, "2", "fine", "How are you", false]]`